# Weierstraß $\sigma$ function identity

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

Let $\Lambda$ be a lattice and $\sigma_{\Lambda_{\tau}}(z):= \sigma(z)= \prod_{w\in \Lambda\setminus \{0\}} \left(1 - \frac{z}{w}\right)\exp\left(\frac{z}{w}+\frac{z^2}{2w^2}\right) $ the Weierstraß sigma function. Furthermore let $\eta_1$ be a quasiperiod of the Weierstraß $\zeta$ function.

For $q = \exp(2 \pi i \tau)$ and $u = \exp(2 \pi i z)$ the following identity holds
\begin{align}
\sigma_{\Lambda_{\tau}}(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \exp\left(\frac{\eta_1 z^2}{2}\right)\left(u^{\frac{1}{2}}- u^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1- q^nu)(1 -q^n u^{-1})}{(1-q^n)^2}.
\end{align} 
I dont really know on how to prove it so i would be glad if anyone could help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this may work : fix $q$, log differentiate in $z$, compare the poles and the behavior at $z=0$ or use $\frac{1}{e^{2i \pi z}-1} =\frac12 +\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{z-n}$ to make $\zeta_\tau(z)$ appear. Then go back to $\sigma$ and compare the behavior at $z = 0$ (where $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1- q^nu)(1 -q^n u^{-1})}{(1-q^n)^2}=1$)